# How to make the whole div clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a menu and have one simple and stupid issue. The problem is: I have my `<span>` elements inside a 'Menu' `div`. With id `'#menu'`. I've made a feature by which you can't accidentally click on the `<a>` inside the `<span>` through CSS `visibility`. But now if you click the menu in space between white stripes, it won't act like a button.

So the question is: *'How to make this `<div>` fully clickable?'*

[Here's the Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/8hxv997y/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not just a link to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be simply do with `width` property, just need to add a width to the menu div:

```css
#menu {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px; /* newly added */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping fixed width, we can also use the width to 100% which gives you more clickable area to collapse the menu

```
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width : 100%; /*newly added*/
  margin: 50px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none
}
```